# D8: Why updated paragraph content does not lead to an updated translation?

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

I created a content type made up with a long-text field and a *multivalue* paragraph field. I create some content adding several paragraphs to the same node, then I choose "Translate" and everything is fine the first time I do this: all original paragraphs appear ready to be translated.

However when I update the original language node adding new paragraphs, these new paragraphs do not appear when editing the translation and I'm forced to delete the latter and create a new translation. Why is this happening?

Comment: You should check https://www.drupal.org/node/2735121, this depends on how you've configured the paragraph fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the comment from @4k4, for most use cases, you want to make the paragraph field untranslatable because it just stores the references to the paragraphs, which are then being translated.

Then you always have the same paragraphs in the same order for all translations.

Translatable paragraph fields are not yet properly supported (this is being worked on in the issue queue) and it should only be done if the paragraph structure must be different for different languages.