# Cannot change layout of translated paragraph nodes

Tags: 9, paragraphs

I make use of Paragraphs to build content nodes along with Drupal's translations to translate a node to a different language. Although the node can be translated, I am unable to move / reshuffle nested elements in the Paragraph layout, some I can do, others not.

[image]

What could possibly be causing this behaviour? Worth noting that on the original version of the node (the default language version) I am able to shuffle these around, it's only on the translated versions that it does not allow us, and also on certain paragraph types, not all of them

Answer (score 1):

Translating the layout is not officially supported yet. See [D8: Why updated paragraph content does not lead to an updated translation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241915/d8-why-updated-paragraph-content-does-not-lead-to-an-updated-translation)

For the classic widget there is this unofficial module https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets.

For the experimental widget this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2904705.